# Issues authenticating, pages not issuing full HTTP headers?

Tags: support, status-completed

I'm behind a firewall that doesn't trust HTTP content without an HTTP content-type header.

When I attempt to OAuth, only on a handful of some of the sister-sites, I receive a notice on pages such as: https://stackexchange.com/users/authenticate

```
Reason: header 'Content-Type' denied rule='Default' value='' 
Method: POST 
Host: stackexchange.com 
Path: /users/authenticate
```

Can we have the server issue the HTTP header? I can't see a reason why we wouldn't be doing so in the first place.

If it's helpful for your debugging, this is my traceroute path:

```
 5  ge10-3.gwy1-mtl.bb.allstream.net (199.212.161.198)  25.673 ms  26.663 ms  27.217 ms
 (Empty section " * * * " redacted)
 11  gwny01.stackoverflow.com (64.34.41.58)  32.925 ms  32.708 ms  35.519 ms
```

And here's the HTTP POST request my user-agent made (sensitive information is redacted)

```
POST /users/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: stackexchange.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 96
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://stackexchange.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2f
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __qca=[redacted]; m=4; gauthed=1; __utma=[redacted]; __utmb=[redacted]; __utmc=[redacted]; __utmz=[redacted].4.3.utmcsr=chat.stackexchange.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; se-usr=t=[redacted]

oauth_version=&oauth_server=&openid_identifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid
```

Comment: Weird, looking into why se.com isn't sending that header; the code is practically identical to stackoverflow's and it *does* send it.

Comment: The failure is intermittent, perhaps there's a node somewhere that changes the header. I'll update in a moment with a tracert.

Comment: To clarify by intermittent, I mean in terms of months. Some months this works, other months this fails. Once auth happens I am not kicked out, but the auth process its self has this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should be sending `Content-Type` down on /users/authenticate from stackexchange.com now.

Looks like the dotNetOpenAuth reference was rather out of date on that site.

Comment: In record time!  =)

Comment: Perfect, I'm authenticated on all domains. Thanks :).